# Hide all Custom ListView Child element when i clicked one

Tags: android

What i want to achieve :-

1. Clicked on the image of custom list view
2. Child element expended
3. Click other image of custom list of another row then opened child list should be close
4. i am trying through visible and gone at holder

Comment: Check this component of android, it might work http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Answer (score 0):

If you would want to expand/collapse any child item of ListView then [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) is the best option.

1. Use [collapseGroup()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#collapseGroup%28int%29) to collapse particular group
2. Use [expandGroup()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#expandGroup%28int%29) to expand particular group

Answer (score 0):

set a last clicked position into a variable as `lastpos` and then check is clicked group position with last clicked position

```
private int lastpos = -1;
private ExpandableListView explv; 


explv.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

@Override
public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
        if (lastpos != -1
                && groupPosition != lastpos) {
            explv.collapseGroup(lastpos);
        }
        lastpos = groupPosition;
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide a single code, it's hard to tell you what to do in **your App**

Here is the tutorial to get it done what you want [Link](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-expandable-list-view-example/)

and if you follow exactly, you will end up like this nice one!

[image]